# SendLog Questions: LookupRow instead LookUp

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, send-email

What i am trying to accomplish is that the online version of an email stays intact after the related dataextension used for sending is updated. Therefore i created the SendLog DataExtension and added a few fields that are commonly used in all dataextensions used for sending.

Currently i am pulling the field values from the dataextension by LookUp, but it seems lackluster to have like 10 LookUp Queries. Since i am uncertain how to pull data into LookUpRow or ClaimRow with a multi-column key as in SendLog (JobID, SubID,BatchID) i ask this question here. And when this is retrieved, how i get the data from the fields from this row.

Feel free to share links or any comment that might help me with sendlog and VAWP which might lead to problems or shows solutions to upcoming problems.

Comment: Too many diverse questions under one topic . Highly suggest splitting them

Comment: I believe Marketing Cloud now caches the view as a webpage for emails that have been sent, so even if you clear a Data Extension the link will still work.

Comment: That is Not true amtera, every vawp will be destroyed if Updates Happen to the sending Data Extension. (If you use These values in the email like personalisation dynamic content etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a Lookuprows you should follow [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm).

But if you try to look into the sendlog DE and retrieve value based on several criteria, you can do it this way:

```
%%[
set @jobid = 13132277 /* a value from my sendlog DE */
set @subID = 93394271 /* a value from my sendlog DE */
set @rows = LookupRows("SendLog","JobID", @jobid,"SubID",@subID)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  var @Value1, @Value2
  set @row = row(@rows,@i) 
  set @Value1 = field(@row,"SubID")
  set @Value2 = field(@row,"Client") /* a custom attribute */

]%%

Value 1: %%=v(@Value1)=%%, Value 2: %%=v(@Value2)=%% <br>

%%[ 
next @i

else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Regarding the documentation LookUpRows only has one parameter to define the criteria, the second and third. Can i just concat them like forever like you did? Example like : `LookupRows("SendLog","JobID", @jobid,"SubID",@subID, "senddate", Now(), "ContentKey", "123", "AnotherColumn", "value", "AnotherColumn2", "value" )`

Comment: As you can see in my example, I was able to add more than 1 criteria. So I guess you can add more. You will have to test it. Good luck.

Comment: Yes you can keep adding where clauses forever if you wish. Just keep in mind this is only 'AND' criteria, there is no 'OR' criteria.