# What is the lifespan of the "web version" of marketing cloud email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

My question is simple (I hope). What is the lifespan of the "web version" of an email sent through the Marketing Cloud.

I have an archive of newsletters on my website. Can I link to the "web version" there, or do I need to recreate everything on my own server to preserve the page?

Answer (score 2):

I goes away when the sending audience is overwritten.  If you want it to persist, then you can send to filtered data extensions and never overwrite the source audience.

Comment: I've seen all of my "web versions" expire after a certain period of time. Can that be disabled or at least extended?

Comment: Man, that's a bummer. One of my lists is constantly evolving. Thanks Adam for the info. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: I do believe there is a default of after X months (It used to be 6, but everything is constantly changing in SFMC - i think it may now be relative to your link expiry settings) the links are wiped - but as Adam said, once the data is changed, the VAWP link will fail which usually happens well prior to the expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider SendLog based VAWP solution. There is a good discussion on the topic [here on SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219032/sendlog-questions-lookuprow-instead-lookup/219048). This will not be affected by changes to your sendable DE